# Rotate iPad while popover is visible and my UITableView moves

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

This is REALLY weird and I'm not sure what the heck is going on.

I've got a UISplitViewController on my iPad app. I can rotate from portrait to landscape over and over and it works exactly as expected. However, if I'm in Portrait orientation and I tap the button to show the popover which contains the left-hand side of the UISplitViewController and then rotate while it is visible, when the rotation is complete the left-hand side table is now pushed down leaving a black gap between it and the Nav Bar.

What the heck could cause that?

I have commented out my `-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration` and `-didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` methods and the problem still exists, so it's not being caused by my rotation code. (That code was just explicitly dismissing that popover).

After the rotation which causes the problem, I recursively printed out the view hierarchy of the left side along with frame sizes:

```
UILayoutContainerView ({{0, 0}, {320, 748}})
     UINavigationBar ({{0, 0}, {320, 44}})
     UILayoutContainerView ({{0, 37}, {320, 711}})
         UINavigationTransitionView ({{0, 0}, {320, 711}})
             UIViewControllerWrapperView ({{0, 44}, {320, 667}})
                 UIView ({{0, 0}, {320, 667}})
                     UITableView ({{0, 0}, {320, 667}})
```

It shows that the navbar is 44 pixels tall, the view container which holds my left-side view controller starts at 0,44 and my tableview within starts at 0,0, but is shorter.... I don't understand why it's not displaying correctly.

Here is what is should look like in landscape orientation. On the left, you'll see the table section header "What do you want to know?" and it is right below the Nav Bar with the "Switch to Calculator" button.

[image]

When I swap to Portrait orientation and tap the "What do you want to know?" button, the popover shows which contains the left-hand side navigation controller with the UITableViewController.

[image]

Now, when I rotate back to landscape, the black gap appears between the nav bar and the UITableView.

[image]

Comment: looks like it's trying to adjust for the nav bar twice.  may try doing a [self.view layoutsubviews]? after the rotation?  or popping down the popover before rotation?

Comment: I tried adding the layoutSubviews and it didn't change anything. I've tried dismissing the popover before rotation, but it was causing a race condition and causing the app to crash. You can see that in my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552490/dismissing-popover-uipopovercontroller-dealloc-reached-while-popover-is-still However, I will see if that is causing this issue.

Comment: Nope, if I remove the dismiss code, the gap still appears.

Answer (score 0):

I remembered having a problem very similar to this last year while working on this app, but I wasn't able to find any old StackOverflow posts about it. However, I remembered that there was some reason why I included the navbar (or rather, made it visible) inside the popover when in portrait mode. For aesthetic purposes, I'd rather have it visible in landscape, but not visible in the portrait popover.. and then I remembered the reason I included it was because it seemed to fix this very problem.

It appeared to be a weird bug in iOS, but showing the Nav Bar is both situations seemed to fix it. So, I decided to change it back to the way I really wanted it to be: visible in landscape, not visible in portrait... and BAM. The black gap disappears. So, it appears that weird bug is still there, but it is working in reverse now.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
        BOOL isPortrait = UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation);

        if (isPortrait) {
            self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        } else {
            self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
        }
    }
}
```